# Android logcat (dev/log/main) problems

Tags: android, logcat

i am having a prob with my cm11 logcat, when i use logcat with ANY parameters, the adb echos
`ioctl: not a typewriter`
and if i use just logcat, it gives me
`read: unexpected length. Expected 28146, got 5100`...
Have tried fixes from other threads
EDIT: after trying something, it now says /dev/log/main no such file or directory

Comment: For the sake of other users, check if you have tweaked in pimp my rom, I think i might have done it that way

Answer (score 0):

Pimp My ROM was causing it. If you mess with the enable/disable features section, you might turn off android logger. I am still not sure if i should have this option on or off, as i cant remember the default.
When it is set to disable the logger, it adds a line to its own script in init.d :
`rm -f /dev/log/main`.
Caused my computer to lag because of a program looking for my phone's logs, checking constantly.
To solve, go to pimp my rom, init.d editor (under rescue package maker) and delete the `99Pimpmyrom` script